# curl (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer - when hitting docker container

Tags: docker, curl, port, dockerfile

getting this error while curl the application ip

curl (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer - when hitting docker container

Answer (score 4):

Do a small check by running:

```
docker run --network host -d <image>
```

if `curl` works well with this setting, please make sure that:

1. You're mapping the host port to the container's port correctly:

```
docker run -p host_port:container_port <image>
```

2. Your service application (running in the container) is running on `localhost` or `0.0.0.0` **and not** something like `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

I GOT the same error:

> umesh@ubuntu:~/projects1$ curl -i localhost:49161
>
> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

In my case it was due **wrong port** no

```
|---MY Projects--my working folder

--------|Dockerfile ---port defined 8080

--------|index.js-----port defined ***3000*** 

--------|package.json
```

Then i was running:

```
docker run -p 49160:8080 -d umesh1/node-web-app1**
```

So as the application was running in port 3000 in index.js it was not able to connect to the application got the error as u were getting

So TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM

Deleted the last container/image that was created my worong port

Just change the port no of INDEX.JS

```
|---MY Projects--my working folder

--------|Dockerfile ---port defined 8080

--------|index.js-----port defined ***8080***

--------|package.json
```

Then build the new image

> ```
> docker build -t umesh1/node-web-app1 .
> ```

running the image in daemon mode with exposed port

> docker run -p 49160:8080 -d umesh1/node-web-app1

**THUS MY APPLICATION WAS RUNNING without any error listing on port 49161**

Answer (score -1):

I have same when bind to port that is not lissened by any service inside container.
So check `-p` option

```
-p 9200:9265
-p <port in container>:<port in host os to be binded to>
```